# UISlider does not appear in the UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, uitoolbar

I have a fairly basic video player I'm creating.  There is a UIToolbar (toolBar) that contains several buttons and a UISlider.  The slider will appear just fine when the toolBar is not a referencing outlet of the View Controller.  Once I link up the toolBar with the view controller, the slider disappears, but all other buttons remain on the toolbar.

I am using a storyboard for the UI, and adding buttons and the slider to the toolbar when the view loads with...

```
UIBarButtonItem *scrubberItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:movieTimeControl];
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexItem, currentPositionLabel, scrubberItem, timeLeftLabel, nil];
```

movieTimeControl is a UISlider property.

I need the toolBar to be an outlet of the controller so that I can dismiss it on specific gestures.

This is how it looks before I link up the toolBar with the controller...
[image: working]

And after linking it with the controller...
[image: not working]

So the space for the slider remains, but the slider is not there.

Any thoughts on why the UISlider is disappearing?

Comment: Try to send UIToolBar to back and bring UISlider to front.
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:slider]; [self.view sendSubViewToBack:toobar];

Comment: No luck on that.  I did end up creating the slider programmatically, including setting it's targets.  This actually got the slider to reappear on the toolbar.  I'd still prefer to have this all done in Interface Builder, with the rest of the project so customization is a bit more uniform.

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger to see if the slider is actually still being created and if so, what its frame is?

Comment: Thanks for the help!  As far as I can see, yes it is being created.  The created UIToolbar has four items (two timestamps, two items for the slider).  How do you check which it's frame?

Comment: I solved the problem... some how.  I added play/pause buttons to the toolbar, and just like that my slider returned.  I'll have to investigate further, but my first suspicion is that the toolbar is requiring play/pause buttons for the slider to be there.  I don't need the play/pause buttons however because I incorporated them onto the slider's thumb.